# jquery iterate list images with timer and hover

Tags: jquery, each, loops, timing

I have a list where li's have img's.  The images are thumbnails and there is another div where the large version of the thumbs should be iterated through.  Also when the user wands over the thumbnail the large image iteration should halt and display what is hovered over.

My hover stuff is working but the iterating & timing is not.  I'm missing something and not surprised as this is really pushing the limits of my capabilities of noob static pages!

simple html:

```
<ul>
 <li><img src='blah' />text</li>
 <li><img src='blah' />text</li>
</ul>
<div ='big'></div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('li img').each(function (i) {
        var thumb = $(this).attr("src");
        setTimeout(function () { 
            $('#big').html('<img src=' + thumb + '/>');

            }, 5000 * (i + 1));
    });

    imgHov();

});

function imgHov(){
    $('li img').hover(
        function(){
            $('#big').html('<img src=' + $(this).attr("src") + '/>');
        },
        function(){
            $('#big').html("");
        }
        );

};
```

I'm up for completely reconstructing this thing; i've tried using jquery .map() and other ways of turning the list into an array instead of .each.  Let me know the direction you experts would go with this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made this for you, take a look...

**Live Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/XcZBq/

Just to know, instead of using `setTimeout`, I used `setInterval` and just put some logic to this, that's all.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're the man!  Of course you have a baby bear!  I don't have your implementation working on my end but the jsfiddle is it.  I need to learn more of the new stuff you exposed me to and dig deeper into the usage of things I have seen but don't quite grasp yet.  I really appreciate this.  Huge help.  Nice images to.  The only real modification is the hover event not pausing the animation; if you stay hovered the animation continues.

Comment: :-) Thanks! well, just to know, if you want to stop the animation there is a method to remove the interval or timeout, I don't remember exactly, just search "remove interval or set timeout in javascript" then when you get the method to remove it, you can invoke this in hover event and then when leaving the hover put again your "setInterval" to continue the animation. Maybe you can put all this in two methods called "start()"  and "stop()" for not repeating the code and handle this in a better way.

Comment: I'll look into that.  Thanks again.  Still learning the map usage and attempting to implement on my local site.

Comment: got it working!  There was a "semantic issue" when inspecting my implementation of your code that needed me to remove some semicolon and then put it back!  weird.  Thank you Oscar!

Comment: Yes, I corrected that at first moment :-) hope you get it working, thank you too.